# Setting variable in Ruby on Rails controller for each do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm building my first rails app and got stuck, and hope someone can help me out. I am looking for the right way to set a variable in the controller to show a button 'enroll' if a user hasnot enrolled (yet) and show a button cancel if the user has already enrolled.

I have a Model Thrills - this are the possible timeslots a for a Training, for a Thrill a User can make a Reservation. These are listed in training/show by:

```
    <% @thrills.each do |thrill| %>
            <%= thrill.thrilldate.strftime("%a %e %b '%y") %>
            <% if booked %>
                Already booked
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "Enroll", thrill_reservations_path(thrill), method: :post , class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

My TrainingsController looks like:

```
  def show
    @thrills = @training.thrills
    @booked = Reservation.where("thrill_id = ? AND user_id = ?", thrill.id, current_user.id).present? if current_user
  end
```

The part @thrill.id seems not properly set as I keep getting errors like:

> (undefined local variable or method `thrill' for 
>   TrainingsController:0x9ffee50)

I have tried several combinations, but I was hoping someone is able to explain briefly what is right and what is the logic behind it. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I now solved temporarily by setting the if-function in the view:

```
<% @thrills.each do |thrill| %>
        <% if Reservation.where("thrill_id = ? AND user_id = ?", thrill.id, current_user.id).present? %>    
            Al geboekt
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Inschrijven", thrill_reservations_path(thrill), method: :post , class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

If anyone has an idea how to set the Reservation.where in the Controller I would really appreciate! Thanks for all the replies I got!

Comment: you've no definition for `@thrill` in any of the code that I can see. You've got `@thrills`, and it's possible you initialize `@thrill` in a before filter. But fundamentally you have to assign something to @thrill before you can use it.

Comment: you only defined `@thrills` in your method, so `@thrill` does not exist. You might want to try looping through `@thrills` (similar to what you did in the .html.erb file) and push each reservation into `booked`.

Comment: Advice on rails. Learn how code debug www.railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel

Comment: Thanks for your help! @davidhu2000 if I want to build your option, what do I call the variable @booked? I tried code like thrill.booked but it says that booked is not a method for thrill. Thanks in advance!